# How would I get a notification bar to display only once per session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a notification bar that I only want to display once per session, or possibly not have the notification display for a predetermined amount of time. I am using session storage but unfortunately I cant get it to work correctly.

Thanks

Here is my code ----------->

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

            var $alertdiv = $('<div id = "alertmsg"/>');
            $alertdiv.text("Join our email list and receive the latest updates at 3Elements Review.");
            $alertdiv.bind('click', function() {
                $(this).slideUp(200);
            });
            $(document.body).append($alertdiv);
            $("#alertmsg").fadeIn("slow"); 
            setTimeout(function() { $alertdiv.fadeOut(400) }, 6000);
                            });

$(window).load(function(){
        if(typeof(window.sessionStorage) != 'undefined') {
        $("#alertmsg").val(window.sessionStorage.getItem('mySessionVal'));
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('mySessionVal', $("#alertmsg").val());
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('storedWhen', (new Date()).getTime());
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you use cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no apparent reason to use window.onload for sessionStorage, DOM ready should suffice ?

Also, you need to check if the value exists in the storage before displaying the message, otherwise the message will always show :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof window.sessionStorage != undefined) {
        if (!sessionStorage.getItem('mySessionVal')) {
    //          ^^^ you can check time here as well ?
            $('<div />', {
                id   : "alertmsg",
                text : "Join our email list and receive the latest updates at 3Elements Review.",
                on   : {
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).slideUp(200);
                    }
                }
            }).appendTo('body').fadeIn("slow").delay(6000).fadeOut("slow");
            sessionStorage.setItem('mySessionVal', true);
            sessionStorage.setItem('storedWhen', Date.now());
        }
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hUXXG/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I noticed you took out the milliseconds on the fade out. How does that affect the slide effect?

Comment: Oh, didn't even notice! Use whatever you'd like, 'slow' should equal 600 milliseconds if I remember correctly, and 'fast' would be 400, but whatever you use it shouldn't matter, only the animation speed is altered.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, that the event handler works, but slideUp doesn't. Try replacing slideUp() with hide() just to see if it works ?

Comment: @MarlonFowler - that's strange, seems to work for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/hUXXG/1/